# How to upsert an array with yq

Tags: yaml, yq

Consider the following `hello.yaml`:

```yaml
foos:
  - foo: foo1
    bar: hello
  - foo: foo2
    bar: world
```

If I want to update the `bar` value where `foo = "foo1"`, I can invoke the following command:

```
yq '( .foos[] | select(.foo == "foo1") | .bar) |= "goodbye cruel"' hello.yaml
```

And that correctly outputs:

```
foos:
  - foo: foo1
    bar: goodbye cruel
  - foo: foo2
    bar: world
```

However, if I do not know that I have an item that matches, I would like to insert the appropriate entries e.g. something like `yq '( .foos[] | select(.foo == "foo3") | .bar) ...` would output

```
foos:
  - foo: foo1
    bar: hello
  - foo: foo2
    bar: world
  - foo: foo3
    bar: goodbye cruel
```

Is there a way in `yq` to "upsert" the array, or do I have to evaluate if the key exists upfront and perform one of two commands to insert or update?

Many thanks

Comment: There is no `upsert` way as of the current version. Best bet would be to check and insert

Answer (score 0):

Like Inian said; there is no upsert operation (at the moment). This is how I would do it - not sure if there is a better way?

```bash
yq '
  with(.foos ;
    select( all_c(.foo != "foo3")) | . += {"foo": "foo3"}
  ) |
  (.foos[] | select(.foo == "foo3") | .bar) = "cool"
' hello.yaml
```

Explanation:

1. In the `with` block, match arrays that *don't* have foo: foo3, and add it.
2. Next, find all the elements with foo: foo3 and update them.

Disclaimer: I wrote yq